# Label doesn't get recognized inside float environment by cleveref package

Tags: floats, cleveref

[Cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package doesn't find the label inside the float environment. Instead, it shows ???

Do I need to add additional properties to float?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{Code}{htbp}{lop}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\Cref{some-reference}

\begin{Code}
   \begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{\texttt{AG\_EVAL}}{$\hat{r}, \mathit{Val}$}
        \If{$\hat{r} \equiv v_0 \texttt{=} g( v_1, \dots, v_n)$}
            \For{$\forall i \in [1, n]$}
                \If{$v_i \not \in \mathit{Val}$}
                    \State Error: \emph{Cannot read attribute instance value before its ready.}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State $\mathit{Val}(v_0) \gets g( \mathit{Val}(v_1), \dots, \mathit{Val}(v_n))$
        \EndIf
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{This is an important code}
\label{some-reference}
\end{Code}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\label` directive *must* come after, not before, the `\caption` statement.

Comment: @Mico updated the question. Didn't solve it.

Comment: @Mico can you please elaborate futher? I am not very familiar with Latex, how to get around this problem?

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replacement of a suitable label string with `??` happens because the OP defines and uses a new float type, called `Code`. While `cleveref` is quite clever, it ain't nearly clever enough to figure out on its own which label string to use for newly-hatched floating environments. Fortunately, the `cleveref` package provides the macros `\crefname` and `\Crefname` just so that users may inform the package which text labels should be used with a newly devised float type.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}%arrows is deprecated

\usepackage{framed,blindtext}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Code}{htbp}{lop} % <-- run this *before* loading `cleveref`

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % load this package *last*
\crefname{Code}{code}{codes} % <-- new
\Crefname{Code}{Code}{Codes} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Cref{some-reference}

\begin{Code}
   \begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{\texttt{AG\_EVAL}}{$\hat{r}, \mathit{Val}$}
        \If{$\hat{r} \equiv v_0 \mathrel{\texttt{=}} g( v_1, \dots, v_n)$}
            \For{$\forall i \in [1, n]$}
                \If{$v_i \not \in \mathit{Val}$}
                    \State Error: \emph{Cannot read attribute instance value before its ready.}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State $\mathit{Val}(v_0) \gets g( \mathit{Val}(v_1), \dots, \mathit{Val}(v_n))$
        \EndIf
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{This is an important code}
\label{some-reference} % <-- always place \label after \caption
\end{Code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would remove it. In stead it you may address importance of order of packages loading (in my comment should be stated "It seems that `geometry` packages should be loaded after `cleveref` instead of a sentence in broken English). What you thing about this?

Comment: You are right, My new test show, that placement of `geometry` in preamble doesn't mater.